# Manage Print Queues using PowerShell or Command Prompt

Tags: powershell, printing, cmd, windows-server-2008-r2

**Windows Server 2008 R2 Print Queue**

I have multiple print queues that get sent to the same printer. When the printer gets these jobs it starts executing them at the same time and mixing the jobs together. I would like a way to manage my print queues using scripts.

**Edit**
To be clear, I want to be able to disable print queues using PowerShell.

Comment: i think this is a serverfault question, nothing to do with programming

Comment: managing print ques with powershell is not programming?

Comment: Your question is a lot more related to infrastructure administration than it is to programming, so [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) would indeed be a better place. Besides, SO isn't a code writing service in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a Server 2016 or a Windows 10 computer. You could use **Implicit Remoting** to load the Print Management Cmdlets for PowerShell. Which may hold a cmdlet that has what you are looking for.

[Print Management Cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh918357.aspx)

In case the link becomes invalid for future users these Cmdlets are included:

```
Add-Printer
Add-PrinterDriver
Add-PrinterPort
Get-PrintConfiguration
Get-Printer
Get-PrinterDriver
Get-PrinterPort
Get-PrinterProperty
Get-PrintJob
Read-PrinterNfcTag
Remove-Printer
Remove-PrinterDriver
Remove-PrinterPort
Remove-PrintJob
Rename-Printer
Restart-PrintJob
Resume-PrintJob
Set-PrintConfiguration
Set-Printer
Set-PrinterProperty
Suspend-PrintJob
Write-PrinterNfcTag
```